# How to string manipulate/extract subject contents in a CSR using OpenSSL command + Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, openssl, csr

I'm currently working to extract properly each contents in a CSR file's subject. I have here a working snippet, However I got stuck when values have a slash / (ex. CSR content has OrganizationUnit = orgunit/testou) on the values. The way I'm doing to extract the contents is to use regex,split it and push that in a Hash, and throw it back in the front end. See below:

```
sub CSRDecode{
###########################################################################
################Do Your Validation#########################################
###########################################################################
my @returnInfo = `openssl req -in /opt2/myfiles/perllib/custom/OpenSSL/certreq.csr -text -noout` or die "Could not validate CSR";
my $Subj= `openssl req -in /opt2/myfiles/perllib/custom/OpenSSL/certreq.csr -subject -noout` or die "Could not validate CSR";
print $Subj;
print @returnInfo;
my $KeySize= @returnInfo[6];


my $SubjAltName =`openssl req -in /opt2/myfiles/perllib/custom/OpenSSL/certreq.csr -text -noout|grep -E 'email|DNS'`; #or die "Could not get SAN";

$KeySize=~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
$KeySize=~/(.+?)/;
$Subj =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

print $Subj;
$SubjAltName=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

my %CSRInfo=split/[=\/]/,$Subj;
if(%CSRInfo){
%CSRInfo->{SubjAltName}.=$SubjAltName;
%CSRInfo->{keysize}.=$KeySize;
}


print Dumper \%CSRInfo;

#######################################################################
```

Input: CSR File with Subject similar to this:

```
subject=/O=ABCCommon/OU=abcfoundation/ops1/emailAddress=allgroup@abccommon.com/L=NYC/ST=AMER/C=AMER/CN=commonName
```

Expected Output after extraction (HASH) - Note the OU content which has "/"

```js
$VAR1 = {
          'CN' => 'commonName',
          'keysize' => 'RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)',
          'SubjAltName' => 'DNS:serverxxx.internal@abc.com, IP Address:192.168.1.1',
          'ST' => 'AMER',
          'O' => 'ABCCommon',
          'emailAddress' => 'allgroup@abccommon.com',
          'subject' => '',
          'OU' => 'abcfoundation/ops1',
          'C' => 'AMER',
          'L' => 'NYC'
        };
```

Currently the output is juggling because I think the regex isn't properly handling the  "split". I'm referring to `my %CSRInfo=split/[=\/]/,$Subj;` in the code snippet. 
I might have some issues in my regex and I appreciate your help, Thank you!

Comment: I think some sample input/output might be useful here, given we can't run your `openssl` command.

Comment: Since you are not using any of the variables that might hold a `/` in the pattern of a regex, that is not a problem. Only if you did `$foo =~ m/$has_slash/` it would be interpreted as part of the pattern. For that you'd use `quotemeta`. But you don't need that.

Comment: @Sobrique I added the input and expected out. I got stuck with this as I'm only relying to string manipulate the subject extracted in the CSR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok. Yes I see. You're trying to split on a `/` but have a pattern including a `/`. This gets complicated, but I'd probably try and approach it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $subj =
    'subject=/O=ABCCommon/OU=abcfoundation/ops1/emailAddress=allgroup@abccommon.com/L=NYC/ST=AMER/C=AMER/CN=commonName';

my %subjinfo = ( $subj =~ m,(\w+)=([^=]*)(?:/|$),g );
print Dumper \%subjinfo;
```

This then gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'subject' => '',
          'L' => 'NYC',
          'C' => 'AMER',
          'OU' => 'abcfoundation/ops1',
          'emailAddress' => 'allgroup@abccommon.com',
          'ST' => 'AMER',
          'CN' => 'commonName',
          'O' => 'ABCCommon'
        };
```

I think that gives what you need. This regular expression repeats, and captures pairs of 'things' on either side of an `=` ending with either `/` or 'end of line' `$`

Because we're matching in pairs (last group has `(?:` to denote it's non-capturing) these can be directly assigned into a hash.

Comment: Hi, Got some complex stuff here, mind if you can also help?
The difference is this format:

`subject=/O=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/OU=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/emailAdd              ress=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/L=CDE/ST=ABC/C=AU/CN=test~@#$^()_+              -=\{}|;':",./<>`

Same stuff, would need to exract this, but with Special character -- sorry I'm new to regex and still learning from it.

Comment: Think that would be better off as a separate question.