# CSR Subject with Special Characters extract

Tags: regex, perl, openssl, csr

I would need to extract the $subj as seen below snippet, but looks like my Regex isn't working as expected. This is actually similar with this: [How to string manipulate/extract subject contents in a CSR using OpenSSL command + Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202477/how-to-string-manipulate-extract-subject-contents-in-a-csr-using-openssl-command/31203632#31203632) but with a different subject entry in the CSR. I'm not sure if I did a good thing in my regex for the %subjinfo

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $subj =
    'subject=/O=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/OU=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/emailAd‌​dress=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/L=CDE/ST=ABC/C=AU/CN=test~@#$^()_+ -=\{}|;':",./<>';

my %subjinfo = ( $subj =~ m,(\w+)=([^=]*)(?:/|$),g );
print Dumper \%subjinfo;
```

and so must give a result to this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'subject' => '',
          'L' => 'NYC',
          'C' => 'AMER',
          'OU' => 'test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>',
          'emailAddress' => 'test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>',
          'ST' => 'AMER',
          'CN' => 'test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>',
          'O' => 'test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>'
        };
```

Is that possible? Can you advise?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting on regex looks more natural than regex only solution,

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $subj = q(subject=/O=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/OU=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/emailAddress=test~@#$^()_+-=\{}|;':",./<>/L=CDE/ST=ABC/C=AU/CN=test~@#$^()_+ -=\{}|;':",./<>);

(undef, my %subjinfo) = split m|/?(\w+)=|, $subj;

print Dumper \%subjinfo;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'emailAddress' => 'test~@#$^()_+-=\\{}|;\':",./<>',
      'CN' => 'test~@#$^()_+ -=\\{}|;\':",./<>',
      'OU' => 'test~@#$^()_+-=\\{}|;\':",./<>',
      'L' => 'CDE',
      'C' => 'AU',
      'ST' => 'ABC',
      'subject' => '',
      'O' => 'test~@#$^()_+-=\\{}|;\':",./<>'
    };
```